# An irreducible representation of $G$ is a $G$-subspace of $\textrm{Ind}_B^G(\chi)$

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, local-field, automorphic-forms

Let $F$ be a local field, and let $G = \textrm{GL}_2(F)$.  Let $B \subseteq G$ be the subgroup of upper triangular matrices, $T$ the diagonal matrices, and $N$ the upper triangular matrices with $1$s on the diagonal.

I'm trying to understand the basics of representations of $\textrm{GL}_2$.  The following lemma is from *Local Langlands Conjecture for $\textrm{GL}_2$* by Henniart and Bushnell.
[image]

Let $V$ be the representation space of $\pi$.  First, I don't understand why if $V$ contains the trivial character of $N$ (that is, if $V$ has an $N$-fixed vector), then $V$ contains an irreducible representation of $B$ containing an $N$-fixed vector.

If $v$ is an $N$-fixed vector, and $w = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, then since $V$ is irreducible, it should be generated as a $T$-space by $v$ and $\pi(w)v$, by the Bruhat decomposition.

I also don't understand how Frobenius reciprocity is coming in.  If $\chi$ is a character of $T$, extended trivially to $B$, then there should be some $B$-map $\pi|_B \rightarrow \chi$ induces an inclusion of $G$-spaces $\pi \rightarrow \textrm{Ind}_B^G(\chi)$.

I would appreciate a hint, not a full solution.

Comment: Hint: also... Jacquet module.

Comment: The existence of the map from $\pi$ to the induced module is basically what Frobenius reciprocity says (it gives a non-zero map since there is a non-zero one for the $B$-modules, and then the fact that $\pi$ is irreducible implies that it is an injection).

Comment: Yes, I'm done once I find a nonzero $B$-map $\pi|_B \rightarrow \chi$ for some character $\chi$.

Comment: Yeah, I know very little about this case. I am mostly familiar with the theory of rational representations for these groups over algebraically closed fields, in which case the theorem would be a bit odd, as both conditions are just true for any irreducible representation.